# My CSS styles are not appearing the same in Firefox as they do in Chrome?

Tags: html, css

My button is Chrome is appearing [like this](http://puu.sh/1waEt).

This is what I want.

In Firefox, however, it appears [like this](http://puu.sh/1waIv).

```
.mainButton_grey { 
  border: 1px solid BFBFBF; 
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#DBDBDB,#D1D1D1);
  padding-top:7px;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
  width:200px;
  height:22px;
  border-radius:3 3;
  background-color:#0972BD; 
  font-size:11px; 
  font-weight:bold; 
  font-family:Arial;
  color:#404040;
 }
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rsxth/1/) here.

Answer (score 2):

Just a word of advice for gradients - if you want as much browser compatibility as possible, add the following (just change the values).

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(black, white); /* FF 3.6+ */  
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #000000), color-stop(100%, #ffffff)); /* Safari 4+, Chrome 2+ */  
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(black, white); /* Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+ */  
background: -o-linear-gradient(black, white); /* Opera 11.10 */  
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#ffffff'); /* IE6 & IE7 */  
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#ffffff')"; /* IE8+ */  
background: linear-gradient(black, white); /* the standard fallback for old browsers */
```

Syntax explanation here: http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-linear-gradient-syntax/

And there's an awesome gradient generator here: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because you haven't defined the linear gradient with:

```
-moz-linear-gradient(top, #DBDBDB, #D1D1D1);
```

The syntax may be a little different; but each browser has a different way to interpret the gradient.

Here is an example of a gradient with each browser:

```
background: rgb(245,246,246); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(245,246,246,1) 0%, rgba(219,220,226,1) 21%, rgba(184,186,198,1) 49%, rgba(221,223,227,1) 80%, rgba(245,246,246,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(245,246,246,1)), color-stop(21%,rgba(219,220,226,1)), color-stop(49%,rgba(184,186,198,1)), color-stop(80%,rgba(221,223,227,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(245,246,246,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(245,246,246,1) 0%,rgba(219,220,226,1) 21%,rgba(184,186,198,1) 49%,rgba(221,223,227,1) 80%,rgba(245,246,246,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(245,246,246,1) 0%,rgba(219,220,226,1) 21%,rgba(184,186,198,1) 49%,rgba(221,223,227,1) 80%,rgba(245,246,246,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(245,246,246,1) 0%,rgba(219,220,226,1) 21%,rgba(184,186,198,1) 49%,rgba(221,223,227,1) 80%,rgba(245,246,246,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(245,246,246,1) 0%,rgba(219,220,226,1) 21%,rgba(184,186,198,1) 49%,rgba(221,223,227,1) 80%,rgba(245,246,246,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f5f6f6', endColorstr='#f5f6f6',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

1. Get your gradient CSS from this site: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/
2. Update your border-radius to specify the units: `border-radius: 3px 3px`;
3. Add `#` to your border-color declaration: `border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;`